# Passing null as Contains() within "linq to sql" query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a problem with Contains in linq to sql query as below:

```
 public IAuditRecord[] Fetch(SearchConditions searchConditions)
    {
        IAuditRecord[] searchedList = (from rows in _dbContex.AuditTrails
                                         where 
                                         (searchConditions.Owner == null || searchConditions.Owner == 0) ? true : rows.Owner == searchConditions.Owner
                                         &&
                                         /*This line cannot compile when ActionIDs array is empty*/
                                         (searchConditions.ActionIDs != null && searchConditions.ActionIDs.Length != 0) ? searchConditions.ActionIDs.Contains(rows.UserActionID) : true
                                         && ((searchConditions.StartDate != null && searchConditions.EndDate != null) ?  (rows.TimeStamp >= searchConditions.StartDate && rows.TimeStamp <= searchConditions.EndDate)
                                         : (searchConditions.StartDate != null && searchConditions.EndDate == null) ?  rows.TimeStamp >= searchConditions.StartDate : (searchConditions.StartDate == null && searchConditions.EndDate != null) ?  (rows.TimeStamp <= searchConditions.EndDate)
                                         : true)
                                       select rows).ToArray();
        return searchedList;
    }
```

This query executes perfectly if searchCondition.ActionIDs array is not null or empty,
but when i pass the ActionIDs array as null the query cannot be compiled.

So the main question is Why contains cannot work when ActionIDs array is null?

Comment: Hmm, everything appears right at first glance. One thing I might suggest to you is to do some research on the Specification pattern. Your predicate (e.g. where clause) for filtering the records is quite complicated to read and understand without really looking hard at it. By creating a few specifications, you can immensely improve the readability of your code and ease your debugging efforts (you'd probably know which specification failed).

Comment: Why would it work? Calling any function on an object set to null should result in a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Because he is checking for null: `searchConditions.ActionIDs != null`.

Comment: Yes when ActionID is null the contains cannot work,Anyway Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're building an `IQueryable`, which defines *how* to query for something, not actually doing it. To do this it builds an `Expression`, which defines all the query intents and can later be called to actually get the data. If you were using LINQ-to-Objects, this would likely work since it would likely call `searchConditions.ActionIDs != null` first, then know that it doesn't have to attempt to execute the second portion. Linq-to-Entities/SQL, etc. don't have that benefit.

Long story short, you can either do:

```
searchConditions.ActionIDs = searchConditions.ActionIDs ?? new int[];
```

Or do a different query if its null, like:

```
var query = _dbContext.AuditTrails;

if(searchConditions.ActionIDs != null && searchCondition.ActionIDs.Length != 0)
{
    query = // Further filtered query where ActionIDs are taken into account.
```

Comment: This is already the last solution for me but i accepted your answer , "new int[]" must change to "new int[]{}" :-), Thank u.